# ASP.NET MVC 5 Custom Role Provider Not Working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, roleprovider, asp.net-mvc-5.2

i have a problem with my custom role providor "string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)" method but the proccess dont go through it. My code is:

**Controller (Just a piece of it):**

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public class UsersController : AdminBaseController
{
    private IUsersRepository users;
    private IDepartmentsRepository departments;

    public UsersController()
    {
        this.users = new UsersRepository(new TicketsContext());
        this.departments = new DepartmentsRepository(new TicketsContext());
    }
}
```

**Custom Role Provider:**

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        var userRoles = GetRolesForUser(username);
        return userRoles.Contains(roleName);
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        //Return if the user is not authenticated
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return null;

        //Return if present in Cache
        var cacheKey = string.Format("UserRoles_{0}", username);
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
            return (string[])HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];

        //Get the roles from DB
        var userRoles = new string[] { };
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.email == username).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            if(user.access_level == 0)
            {
                userRoles = new[] { "Administrator" };
            }
            else
            {
                userRoles = new[] { "Normal" };
            }
        }

        //Store in cache
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, userRoles, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

        // Return
        return userRoles.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<!-- Custom Role Provider -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TicketsRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="TicketsRoleProvider"
         type="Tickets.CustomRoleProvider"
         cacheTimeoutInMinutes="30" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I cant get it to work, and i dont know why.

Can anyone help me pls ?

Thanks

Comment: That's because it uses the IsUserInRole method of the role provider. Step into that method.

Comment: if i put a break point in that method ("IsUserInRole") still the same, dont pass through it. I added the method in the questions, take a look pls.

Comment: a bit late comment to this question, but in your example there is no way how to setup cacheTimeoutInMinutes > so i wonder if it is in default value (0)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obvious, but I would:

- Remove the check for "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" in the GetRolesForUser method.  This method should just get the roles for the username supplied as an argument.
- To debug, I'd start by examining `HttpContext.Current.User.GetType()` inside a controller action method (one that isn't secured).  Is it of type `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal`?
- You should implement `IsUserInRole` in your custom `RoleProvider`.  The implementation can just check that the supplied role is in the array returned by `GetRolesForUser`.  I don't think this is your problem though: `IsUserInRole` isn't used by `RolePrincipal` (though it is used by `System.ServiceModel.Security.RoleProviderPrincipal` if you use ASP.NET roles in a WCF service, so it's a good idea to implement it anyway.

**UPDATE**

You've confirmed `HttpContext.Current.User` is a `RolePrincipal`.  I suggest you examine it closely using the debugger.  In particular examine:

- the `ProviderName` property, which should match the name of your custom RoleProvider.
- the `Identity` property, which should match the name of the current user.

You might also try calling `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole` from code in your controller.  The first time this is called, it should call your custom RoleProvider's GetRolesForUser method.

You can also try calling the `RolePrincipal.SetDirty()` method: this marks the cached role list as having been changed, and the next call to `IsInRole` or `GetRoles` should call your custom RoleProvider's GetRolesForUser method again.

Comment: Thanks ;) I already implemented IsUserInRole in my custom RoleProvider and debug the GetType and yes it is of type System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal, print screen -> http://s21.postimg.org/3y21l6jyf/debug.png

Comment: @kanazaca - see update for some more debugging tips.

Comment: how can i check if the ProviderName returns my custom RoleProvider ? When i use User.IsInRole returns the wrong value, seems that is not using my custom role provider.

Comment: @kanazaca - does the name match what's in web.config (TicketsRoleProvider)?  Is the Type of Roles.Providers[ProviderName] the correct type (Tickets.CustomRoleProvider)?  Is it possible you have another assembly with this type?  Try overriding the Initialize method in your custom RoleProvider and add a breakpoint in it to see if it's hit.  Check that you've added your custom RoleProvider to the web.config in the application root, and not in a subdirectory (such as in the Views subdirectory)